# What does this software do when it says "white labeled routing"?

Tags: project-management, software, startup, company

I am reading about a start-up [company](http://federatedsample.com/) that works with online surveys:

> Fulcrum is the world’s first complete project management suite to give
>   clients the power to seamlessly integrate multiple suppliers, increase
>   productivity and reduce costs.  Ranging from vertically integrated
>   research firms to sample suppliers, clients who license Fulcrum enjoy
>   increased efficiency and with minimal technology development costs.
>   This simplified survey management platform boasts white-labeled
>   routing and improved respondent experience all while giving clients
>   exceptional control and sample quality.

I am a little confused about what's going on. What is " white-labeled routing" ?

OK, I found out a "panel" company is a surveying company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the lines of a [White Label Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product), it means that their software can sit behind the client's software and route it to another destination transparently--that is, making it look like it was the client's software that sent it.

Really, the makers of Fulcrum are saying that their clients can use their own proprietary front end or Fulcrum's front end, and nobody at the other end will be any the wiser.

Answer (score 2):

The term "[white label](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product)" generally refers to a product that allows the purchaser of the product to customize the product so that it looks like their own.  In this case, if Walter's Widgets buys the product, Walter's Widgets can likely add their own logos and send the surveys through their own servers so that a customer has no idea that Fulcrum (or any other third party) is involved in the process.  This would look a lot more professional than having your customers receive mail from some third party they've never heard of or being directed to a third-party site they're not familiar with.  And it generally gives the purchaser much more control over the user experience.